# Ratio of heights of a sphere,over and under water

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

When a sphere is floating in the water, only 10 % of the volume is above the surface, while the rest is below. I need to calculate the relationship between height for the part above, and below the water.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1463803/1508) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3148382/1508).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The volume of a spherical cap is given by the formula (a formula worth remembering)

$ V_{cap} = \dfrac{1}{3} \pi h^2 (3 R - h) $

While the total volume of the sphere is

$ V_{sphere} = \dfrac{4}{3} \pi R^3 $

Divide the two you get

$ \dfrac{1}{10} = \dfrac{ h^2 (3 R - h) } {4 R^3} = \dfrac{3}{4} \alpha^2 - \dfrac{1}{4} \alpha^3 $

where $\alpha = \dfrac{h}{R} $

Solving the cubic equation in $\alpha$, results in

$\alpha \approx 0.3916 $

Hence, $ h = 0.3916 R $ and $ H = 1.6084 R $

Comment: Where did you derive “H” from at the end?

Comment: From $h + H = 2 R$